# JPA / Jackson - Exclude fields when deserialize and include them when serialize

Tags: java, serialization, spring-boot, jackson

I have a JPA entity with a couple of fields (the real ones are more complex). I'm receiving *some data* via REST (`POST` operation in a Spring controller) and storing it right away in the JPA entities; I want to see if there is a possibility to exclude some field(s) when the request is sent, Jackson deserializes it, and constructs the object. But at the same time I want those fields to be included when I send back (object gets serialized) the response.

```
@Table("key_card")
public final class KeyCard {
  private String username; // Don't want this to be sent as input,
                           // but want to be able to send it back
                           // in the response
  @NotBlank
  private final char[] password;
}
```

I'm just trying not to model it twice (for the request and response) if there is a way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON views: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonView

```
Class Views {

   static class AlwaysInclude { }
   static class OnlyOnSerialize extends AlwaysInclude { }

}
```

And then on your view:

```
@Table("key_card")
public final class KeyCard {

  @JsonView(Views.OnlyOnSerialize.class)
  private String username;

  @JsonView(Views.AlwaysInclude.class)
  @NotBlank
  private final char[] password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a Java object property only from Json deserialization and to include instead  its value during serialization you can use an appropriate combination of **@JsonIgnore** and **@JsonProperty** annotations.

In particular you should:

- annotate with @JsonIgnore the property itself
- annotate with @JsonIgnore its set method
- annotate with @JsonProperty its get method

Here you can find an in-depth explanation and an example: [Jackson: using @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty annotations to exclude a property only from JSON deserialization](http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/)